# Display a button in ribbon when arriving to a step of a stage in a process flow in Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I need your help: How I can display a button in ribbon when arriving to a step of a stage in a process flow in Dynamics CRM 2015?

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: do you already have the button on the ribbon or do you need to create the button as well?

Comment: I have created th button on the ribbon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the Process stage:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute('stageid').getValue()
```

and the following code to get the ribbon button:

```
var btnRunWorklfow=top.document.getElementById("account|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.account.RunWorkflow-Large");
```

To hide the button, you can use a javascript similar to this in one in one of the form or control events:

```
var stageID = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("stageid").getValue();
if (stageID == 'xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx') {

    var btnRunWorklfow=top.document.getElementById("account|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.account.RunWorkflow-Large");
    btnRunWorklfow.style.display='none';

}
```

You can also use ribbon editor available in codeplex to disable your button based on your javascript.

refer: http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/

This is also an useful link: [Hiding/Showing a Section Based on the Current Stage](http://www.fmtconsultants.com/2014/10/business-process-flows-in-dynamics-crm-2013-hidingshowing-a-section-based-on-the-current-stage/)